# CiviCRM 'Detailed Logging' removes former 'Changelog' entries on contacts

Tags: logging

CiviCRM 4.7.x

We used CiviCRM for many years and relied upon the normal 'changelog' then we enabled 'Detailed Logging' a few weeks ago, and the old entries from the tab disappeared. Do they still exist in the DB or a file, and are they recoverable and able to be displayed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the Report `Contact Logging Report (Summary)`, that is used to display the detailed logging, requires the permission `CiviCRM: administer CiviCRM`. [image]

If you create a CiviCRM user without this permission, you will be able to access the regular change log. This will include the entries before and after you enabled detailed logging.

This is a very usefull feature to ensure data privacy when having unprivileged backend users.

Comment: I dig this answer the most, thanks Thomas.

Comment: At what URL can I find this edit screen please?

Comment: @BrunoVincent Once logging is enabled it will be listed under https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/report/list?reset=1. On dmaster it is currently under https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/report/instance/41?force=1&reset=1, but your report instance id will very likely be different.

Answer (score 3):

They should still exist in the civicrm_log table if you have access to the DB.

Comment: You can also view those entries with an unprivileged civicrm user.

Comment: Thomas, can you say more about that?